# Where are screenshots saved in Tag: Power of Paint?

Tags: tag-the-power-of-paint

Even though there are billboards in the game telling you how to take screenshots (plus a little notification when you do), I've dug through the game files and can't find the ones I've taken anywehre. Lil' help?

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7 and Vista, they're stored under `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\Tag\Screenshots`.

Programs in 7 and Vista are limited in the changes they can make to protected areas, e.g. `Program Files`, and their efforts are instead redirected to a user-specific virtual space to maintain some level of compatibility.  See the [related MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927387) for more.

Under XP and older versions of Windows, they should be stored in the `C:\Program Files\Tag\Screenshots` folder.

Comment: Great stuff, cheers.